# Why does 'const' behave differently in these two cases?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, qualifiers

I have a question about just why a certain thing can be compiled when done "in one step" but can't when done "in two steps". I have three classes;

```
class Time {
  int mTime;

  int Time::getTimeAsUnix() const {return mTime;}
}

class Travel {
  Time mTimestamp;

  const Time& Travel::getTime() const { return mTimestamp; }
  Time& Travel::getTime() { return mTimestamp; }
}

class Analysis : public Travel {

  int Analysis::getUnixTime() const {
    // Time& t = Travel::getTime();
    // return t.getTimeAsUnix();     // This does NOT compile

    return Travel::getTime().getTimeAsUnix();  // This compiles
  }
}
```

Anyone knows why, in the Analysis class, the non-commented approach compiles while the commented approach gives me an instant *"c++ error: binding 'const Time' to reference of type 'Time&' discards qualifiers"* when I try?

Aren't the two the exact same thing when executed??

Comment: Have you tried `const Time& t = Travel::getTime();` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the line that doesn't compile is `Time& t = Travel::getTime();` since the method you are in is itself const and will refuse to call a non-const method. In short, this is not because you do it in two steps, it is because you explicitly call the non-const method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
Time& t = Travel::getTime();
```

needs to be

```
const Time& t = Travel::getTime();
```

for it to work.  The reason this is needed is because you are inside a const-qualified function.  When you are in  a const-qualified function all members of the class are considered to be `const`.  That means when you call `getTime` you call the

```
const Time& Travel::getTime() const { return mTimestamp; }
```

version of the function.  Trying to assign a `const Time&` to a `Time&` wont work because you would be stripping away the constness of the return type.

Answer (score 4):

In this function definition where you shall remove `Analysis::`

```
  int Analysis::getUnixTime() const {
     Time& t = Travel::getTime();
     return t.getTimeAsUnix();  
  }
```

there is called the function

```
const Time& Travel::getTime() const { return mTimestamp; }
```

that returns a constant reference. It is this overloaded function is used because the function `getUnixTime` declared as a const member function.

However the constant reference is assigned to a non-constant reference

```
     Time& t = Travel::getTime();
```

so the compiler issues an error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's break down the working version:

```
int Analysis::getUnixTime() const { // (1)
    // (2) --------v        v----- (3)
    return Travel::getTime().getTimeAsUnix();
}
```

At `(1)`, the function `getUnixTime` is defined to work on a constant instance. That means you can only call other constant functions and can't change any member variables.

At `(2)`, `Travel::getTime()` is called. This call a *non-static member function*, depite its syntax. But that's okay, it's clear and calls the `const` version of the function, which return `const Time&`. A reference to a constant `Time` object.

At `(3)`, the member function `getTimeAsUnix` gets called on a `const Time&`.  This is perfect because `Time` has a member function named that way that is marked to work on constant objects.

So as you see, every objects are constant and you only call constant function.

---

What went wrong when you broke down the code in two lines?

Let's take a look at the first line in the body of you function:

```
Time& t = Travel::getTime();
```

As we stated, `Travel::getTime()` calls a *non-static member function*. Since `this` is a constant object (you're in a const function) then the const version of `getTime` gets called, just as before.

The return type of the const `getTime` is `const Time&`.

Then you do `Time& t =`. This is where you error is. `const Time&` cannot be modified. A `Time&` can be modified. If you refer to a constant object using a mutable reference, then you'd be able to mutate constant object. The language prohibit that!

To fix this, simply use constant references:

```
const Time& t = Travel::getTime();
```